# How to differentiate between annotation pins?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have three pins on a mapview.  I'd like to give each one a different color.  In the delegate method viewForAnnotation, I'm doing this:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation{
MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"anAddress"];
annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
annView.animatesDrop=TRUE;
annView.canShowCallout = YES;
annView.calloutOffset = CGPointMake(-5, 5);
return annView;
}
```

I was thinking to create an array of MKPinAnnotationViews but how can I get the correct one since the delegate method isn't indexed to anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To distinguish between `UIView`, you can use [the `tag` property](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag) and its corresponding `viewWithTag:` method.

However, in your context, I would recommend adding the color to your annotation class.  Then you can ensure that you don't reuse the same caller for multiple pins.

Comment: You mean by making a custom MKPinAnnotationView?  But still, how do I call the correct one when the delegate fires?  Or does it matter?  If not, I can just keep a class level counter to pull them out of an array upon each firing of the delegate.

Comment: I mean that your id<MKAnnotation> class contains a field for the color indicator, or a counter you use to determine the color.